# Android Webview buttons not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am making a html app, and running it on Android in a webview. Everything works perfectly as expected on my samsung s3 mini and a couple of other devices that I have tested it on, however the button presses have no effect on some other devices (for example htc wildfire... I am in the process of finding out which devices don't work).

The css for the buttons is:

```
button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 10px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 10px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 10px 0px #000000;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00ff00), color-stop(1, #00ff00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #00ff00 5%, #00ff00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ff00', endColorstr='#00ff00');
    background-color:#00ff00;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:42px;
    border-top-left-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:42px;
    border-top-right-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:42px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:42px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:42px;
    text-indent:0px;
    border:1px solid #006400;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height:46px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #00ff00;
    width:7em;
}

button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00ff00), color-stop(1, #00ff00) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #00ff00 5%, #00ff00 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ff00',         endColorstr='#00ff00');
    background-color:#00ff00;
}

button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

and one of the buttons has:

```
.button-wrap {
    width:auto;
}
```

interestingly the button with `class="button-wrap"` was the only button that worked on one device.

The HTML for the buttons is simple:

```
<button class="button-list-spacing" id="play-game-button">Play!</button>
```

and the js behind them is:

```
$("#play-game-button").click(function (e) {
    window.location.replace("gamepage.html?soundon=" + SOUND_ON);
});
```

Does anyone know any thing that could cause a button to not respond to clicking? I will edit in the future with a list of devices that it works on, and a list that it doesn't.

Edit:

The buttons do not work on 
* Samsung galaxy tab 7.0 GT-P6200, Android version 3.2

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yuy7F/

I have posted a related question here that might be worth checking out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595810/android-webview-messes-up-in-4-1-1-but-not-4-1-2

Comment: Is it normal that you declare your class in HTML as `...=".button-wrap"` with the dot?

Comment: A fiddle will help understanding your question

Comment: Sorry, typo when copying, I have fixed it to ...="button-wrap"
@aravind I have added a fiddle in the edit.

Comment: @aravind Oops, sorry, forgot to include it. I have edited it in.

Comment: Did you find any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using a framework like jquery.

Make sure all javascript files of the framework are available, or try this:

```
<button class="button-list-spacing" id="play-game-button" onclick="window.location.replace("gamepage.html?soundon=" + SOUND_ON);">Play!</button>
```

And make surevthe SOUND_ON variable is available.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the jquery stuff just in case, but it didn't help. (as it worked ok on the other versions I doubted it was the issue).

Comment: Try replacing the <button> by an <input type="button">